# React this.props is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I've got a pretty standard setup, a router with pages:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, Link, hashHistory as history } from "react-router";

import Layout from "./pages/Layout";
...
import User from "./pages/User";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={...}/>
        <Route path="project/create" component={...}/>
        <Route path="project/:id" component={...}/>
        <Route path="user/:id" component={User}/>
        <Route path="*" component={...}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("app-root"));
```

Everything is working perfectly except when I go to a page like `site.tld/#/user/5`. The `User` component has some trouble getting instantiated properly. All other pages are working, I also have another page that uses url parameters (`project/:id`) and it is working fine as well.

```
import React from "react";
...

export default class User extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    console.log(this);
    
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return ...
  }
```

This is what I get in the console.

[image]

I'm sure it's the dumbest thing ever again, but I can't pick it out...

Comment: Typically you pass the props received in the constructor up to the Component superclass: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781

Comment: Try logging `this.props` in the `render()` method to verify.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen You are correct, props are available in render but not in the constructor, passing props in the constructor makes no difference in my code :/

Comment: Why do you need it? I mean, yes, important to understand why you can't use `this.props` but you DO have the `props` available as the first argument to the constructor. Simply pass this object around to whatever function or logic you're trying to come up with maybe?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I think you're missing the following, try replacing your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(this.props)
}
```

Try it out, you should get output from `this.props`.

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
> When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
> should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
> this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
> bugs. Source: [**ReactJS.org Component Docs**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Comment: I tried that, it's not working. I have the same constructors in all pages and I have access to props in the other pages' constructors.

Comment: @php_nub_qq did you do super(props)? not just super() and not empty constructor() instead constructor(props)

Comment: @php_nub_qq, there was a typo. Not sure if you saw it or copied it straight off and got it wrong...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I forgot to **bind** the method that I was calling, that's why `props` was undefined.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.changeScreenToForm = this.changeScreenToForm.bind(this);
}

changeScreenToForm() {
    this.props.app.changeScreen(Form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case this -

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   console.log(this.props);
}
```

still gave `undefined`.

I had to use `this.props = props;` explicitly and it worked.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
}
```

Comment: You are probably extending something else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case *(react: 17.0.1)*:

If you have constructor in you class, then you will have to initialize props like this

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

If there is nothing happening in you constructor, then simply removing the constructor worked for me and **this.props** worked as expected. The case when I got this error was having a constructor like this

```
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch my

```
import { Output } from './Output';
```

to

```
import Output from './Output';
```

I'm very new to React and JS in general but that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

React.js noob btw;

first it was like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
...
```

got the error ( 'props' is not defined )

then I just deleted (props) from super
like this

```
constructor (props) {
    super();
...
```

and that solved it and everything loaded perfectly.