# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

i got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` when i tried to change the props of state in react-redux, here's my code to change:

```
class Home extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchMatches();
  }

  handleChange(newDateRange){
    this.props.fetchMatches({
      ...this.props,
      startDate: newDateRange[0],
      endDate: newDateRange[1]
    })
  }
```

Comment: You can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858542/react-this-props-is-undefined

Comment: @MuhammadAsifJaved The answer you sent has `this.props` as undefined. In this case, `this` is undefined.

Comment: try to bind the "this" in your constructor. this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
handleChange = (newDateRange) => {
    this.props.fetchMatches({
      ...this.props,
      startDate: newDateRange[0],
      endDate: newDateRange[1]
    })
  }
```

or in constructor, do

```
constructor(){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

In `handleChange`, it is not able to find the `context`, due to which `this` is undefined. Either you'll have to explicitly bind `this` or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: but the state doesn't change!

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say here. That should resolve your issue which you asked in the question.