# how this.props available in react class render()?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

*how this.props available in react class `render()` ?, but I have not passed any props in
constructor and super ex :*

```
class App extends react.Component
{
   constructor(){
      super() //here we have not passed the props to the parent class
   }
   render (){
        this.props  //why not undefined ?
   }
<app name="ashwin"/>
```

Why `this.props` is undefined?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please help........

Comment: does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858542/react-this-props-is-undefined

Comment: why do you use class components? AFAIK function components are preferred in React JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React this.props is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42858542/react-this-props-is-undefined)